# Use Tab to move from one field to another across multiple SubForms

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have one `unbound mainForm` that contains 9 `continuous SubForms`. I used `SubForm1` as proxy parent and linked one textbox on `mainForm` to `ID` of `SubForm1`. This `ID` is then used as `parentField` for other 8 `child subForms`. The arrangement works great and is really fast in moving across records for data entry/ data editing. However, I have a challenge when I want to use `TAB` button to move from one `textBox in SubForm1` to another `textBox in 'SubForm2`. I have to use `Ctl + Tab` to move across forms at the moment. I know it is happening because of multiple `SubForms` but to my user I want to give a feel as if it is just one screen. My user expects web like experience to only use `Tab` button to move across controls. Is there any way that I can achieve it without using `Ctl` button?

Answer (score 0):

If you can know when you will be on the last record in your subform1 for example, you could check for the keyDown event and focus on the next subform.

something like this:

```
Private Sub last_control_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
On Error Resume Next
If Shift  = 0 Then ' this is tab , then go to next subform
subForm2.setFocus
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Combine this idea with by-subform boolean flags that are set when the last control gets the focus and reset when focus returns to the subform?